# NextJS 14 - Cache not revalidating on Vercel servers

Tags: next.js, caching, vercel

I've got a project where on my homepage I've got some stats about it. As I don't want to fetch this from database every time, I tried to implement some caching here. However it seems cache not get invalidated correctly on vercel servers.

My code:
I've got client component which fetch data from API:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<HomePageAllStats>(null as any);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`URL/api/stats`, { cache: 'no-store' });
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
}
```

In client component I obviously don't have any caching. After that I have my api route:

```
export async function GET() {
  try {
    const statsPromise = unstable_cache(getStats, ['stats'], { revalidate: 60 });
    const stats = await statsPromise();
    const mappedCountryStats = mapStats(stats.source);
    const data: HomePageAllStats = {
      totalCount: stats.total,
      countries: mappedCountryStats,
    };
    return Response.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting stats:', error);
    return Response.json({});
  }
}

async function getStats(): Promise<TotalStats> {
  const documentReference = await admin.firestore().collection('stats').doc('total').get();
  return documentReference.data() as TotalStats;
}
```

Here I'm using unstable_cache for 60 seconds revalidation. (I prefer to revalidate on server not client, so someone can not spam my API and always get new resutls).

Issue:
It seems like if I build this code with build and start command, everything works fine, after 1 minute cache get revalidated and shows new results.

When I deploy it on vercel it behave strange. First request after build show new results from database. But after I do full page reload some old data load from a cache. Which was valid like day ago or something.

Any idea what can be wrong with my code? Or what I can try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**

> *I'm using unstable_cache for 60 seconds revalidation. It seems like if I build this code with build and start command, everything works fine, after 1 minute cache get revalidated and shows new results.When I deploy it on vercel it behave strange. First request after build show new results from database. But after I do full page reload some old data load from a cache. Which was valid like day ago or something.*

**Possible Cause :**

- You used **unstable_cache** : There is a warning[1](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache) that this is API, is unstable and may change in the future.

**Possible Solution :**

- **Route Segment Config** allows you to configure the behavior of a page, layout, or route handler by setting various options [3](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config).

Add `export const revalidate = 60` at top of route file `/api/stats` this will set  revalidation frequency to 60 seconds.

```
export const revalidate = 60
export async function GET() {
...
...

}
```

So API calls coming under 60 seconds will get same data, after 60 seconds data will be re-fetched on API call cached & then given.

**Please Read :**

- **unstable_cache :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache
- **revalidate :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate
- **Route Segment Config :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***

Comment: As much as I am surprised, it seems this simple solution actually worked. Upvoting + Accepting answer.